# Render static HTML with assets folder in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have an Elixir project generated with: `mix new . --sup httpserver`

This follows a short video found [here](https://youtu.be/_TjXYGXG2z8).

This is a very simplistic plain text "hello world" (plus a little). I wanted to see if I could serve static pages (e.g. `index.html`) with assets located in an `assets` folder co-located with the `index.html`.

If I put the `index.html` and `assets` in the root of the project, I can send the `index.html` with the following command:

`send_file(conn, 200, "index.html", 0, :all)`

However—I do not yet see how to send the `asset` files when the follow-on asset requests arrive. Can someone give me that direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Plug.Static](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html):

Put the following in your router before `plug :match` (in a Phoenix project, the endpoint is a better place):

```elixir
plug Plug.Static, at: "/", from: "assets"
```

From the docs:

> - `:at` - the request path to reach for static assets.   It must be a string.
> - `:from` - the file system path to read static assets from.